# jqTree shows undefined for valid json

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtree

I am trying to use the jqTree from http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/#tutorial

my page is

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <HTML>
     <HEAD>
      <TITLE> Json Parser </TITLE>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqtree.css">
       <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/tree.jquery.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">


 $(function() {
   var data = [{"tweetText":"RT @dna: IPL spot-fixing: Jagmohan Dalmiya still clueless about N Srinivasan's return http://t.co/PwDniu8sJg","urlsMentioned":[],"usersMentioned":[{"userId":17710740,"screenName":"dna","userName":"dna"}],"source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>","tweetId":362907208733827100,"reTweetCount":12,"reTweeted":true,"createdDate":"Thu Aug 01 12:06:35 UTC 2013","user":{"location":"","userId":24525170,"screenName":"varuntripathi1","userName":"varun","profileDescription":"","language":"en"},"reTweetedStatus":{"tweetText":"IPL spot-fixing: Jagmohan Dalmiya still clueless about N Srinivasan's return http://t.co/PwDniu8sJg","urlsMentioned":["http://dnai.in/bAoD"],"usersMentioned":[],"source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/tweetbutton\" rel=\"nofollow\">Tweet Button</a>","tweetId":362606709404991500,"reTweetCount":12,"reTweeted":false,"createdDate":"Wed Jul 31 16:12:31 UTC 2013","user":{"location":"India","userId":17710740,"screenName":"dna","userName":"dna","profileDescription":"We are India’s favourite English daily delivering news, views & analyses. Follow us for real-time news updates. PS: This Twitter feed is not operated by a bot.","language":"en"},"hashTags":[]},"hashTags":[]}]
$('#tree1').tree({ 
    data: data
});
 });
   </script>
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
    <div id="tree1">
    </div>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

It does not show any value. but it is workinf fine for the data 
var data = [
    {
        label: 'node1',
        children: [
            { label: 'child1' },
            { label: 'child2' }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'node2',
        children: [
            { label: 'child3' }
        ]
    }
];

even though both json are valid one. How would i solve this or any other js available to select the nodes of a json.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xQSLw/2/)

Is there anyother  js available to view the json.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would jqTree accept that arbitrary JSON? You need to sanitize and restructure it first. @LeGEC's answer points you in the right direction. How do you expect the output to look?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you probably have already figured out, `valid JSON` != `valid data`.

You need to provide the constructor with data that corresponds to its requirements.

In the case of jqTree, that is

```
[
    {
        "label":"node 1",
        "children": [
            {
                "label": "node 1.1"
            },
            {
                "label": "node 1.2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "node 2"
    }
]
```

etc.

So, you need a function to reformat the data, such as:

```
function formatData(arr) {
    var label, data = [], obj, node;
    if(!$.isArray(arr)) {
        arr = [arr];
    }
    console.log(arr);
    var l = arr.length, i;

    for(i=0; i< l; ++i) {
        node = {};
        obj = arr[i];
        node.label = obj.user.screenName + ": " + obj.tweetText + " (" + obj.createdDate + ")";
        if(typeof obj.reTweetedStatus == "object") { //fetch children
            node.children = formatData(obj.reTweetedStatus);
        }
        data.push(node);
    }

    return data;
}
```

which will return something like

```
[{
    "label": "varuntripathi1: RT @dna: IPL...Jg (Thu Aug 01 12:06:35 UTC 2013)",
    "children": [{
        "label": "dna: IPL spot-fixing: Ja...Jg (Wed Jul 31 16:12:31 UTC 2013)"
    }]
}]
```

This creates a tree that looks something like this:

[image: jqTree output]

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/xQSLw/16/)

---

On a side note, I believe that it will be difficult for you to do what you want with jqTree. It is relatively difficult to customize, in my view.

You can find more configurable jQuery tree widgets, such as [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) or [zTree](http://www.ztree.me/) in [jQuery's plugin site](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/tree/).

I created a short example with zTree that produces a the following tree based on your data:
[image: zTree's output]
[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/jJS8B/)

Answer (score 1):

Your data variable is not a JSON, JSON is a formatted string that you can parse to get a get a javascript object in this case.

A proper JSON string of that object is: `var jsonData = "[{"label":"node1","children":[{"label":"child1"},{"label":"child2"}]},{"label":"node2","children":[{"label":"child3"}]}]"`

Although I haven't ever used jqTree, I typed your example in Plunker to check how tree work with the three types of data; you data, a json data get from javascript object and the object get from that json data.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Sw3BCigiU69jLkQkAw5U?p=preview

Comment: see my edited code. I checked that json in online json viewer. It is working but here only not working

Comment: Could you have any idea on this? or is there any other js available to to select the json node

Comment: What Ivan is saying, @jackyesind, is that `var data = [{ "..." }];` is not a valid JSON value. In your question, it's an array with a single JavaScript object. Note the different location of the quotes in `var data = "[{ ... }]";`, which is a JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

```
[{
   "club":
         { "id":1,"name":"This is a team name"},
   "members":
         [
             {"id":2,"name":"Test Name"},
             {"id":3,"name":"Another Name"},
             {"id":4,"name":"More Names"},
             {"id":5,"name":"Cool Person"}]
}];
```

Put [ and ]

Comment: include jquery-1.9.1.min.js not jquery-2.0.3.min.js may verson problem

Comment: Could you have any idea on this? or is there any other js available to to select the json node

Comment: I want json viewer not tree view of folder

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34676/discussion-between-manoj-and-jackyesind)

Comment: here they blocked chat options

Comment: Is there any jstree with check box near to the node to select that node?

Comment: you can add checkbox for node that you want by DOM manipulation by jquery.

Comment: My need is i want check box for the parent node and if i select the check box in the parent node. when i click save the selected checkbox value should be saved

Comment: could you help me on this? currently i am using http://www.daviddurman.com/jquery-json-editor-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my answer, can u please try this

```
 var data = [
"club":
        [{"id":1,"name":"This is a team name"}],
"members":
        [{"id":2,"name":"Test Name"},{"id":3,"name":"Another Name"},{"id":4,"name":"More Names"},{"id":5,"name":"Cool Person"}]
];
```

Comment: Same problem Nothing is displayed

Comment: what your console says?

Comment: missing ] after element list

"club":

Comment: Could you have any idea on this? or is there any other js available to to select the json node

Answer (score 0):

I tried by adding a extra brace around the json data returned from the server and worked

```
 $.post(your_url, null, function (data) {
    //add extra braces before binding to the tree
    data = $.parseJSON("[" + data + "]");        
    $('#tree1').tree({
        data: data,
        autoOpen: true,
        dragAndDrop: true
     });
  });
```

Comment: try it here - http://jsfiddle.net/xHUWC/. You'll need to modify your json to match mine meaning there should be name, id, children properties for each of your tree nodes. At first I thought you are loading data from server. I have the problem with missing braces while loading from server.

Answer (score 0):

The following json data works.

```
var data = [
    {
        label: 'RT @dna: IPL spot-fixing: Jagmohan Dalmiya still clueless about N Srinivasan\'s return http://t.co/PwDniu8sJg',
        children: [
            {
                label: 'IPL spot-fixing: Jagmohan Dalmiya still clueless about N Srinivasan\'s return http://t.co/PwDniu8sJg'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

By the way, what do you want to show exactly in the tree?

Comment: I want to display the above json in  a tree